# Asynchronous nodejs module exports

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I was wondering what the best approach is for configuring a module export. "async.function" in the example below could be a FS or HTTP request, simplified for the sake of the example:

Here's example code (asynmodule.js):

```
var foo = "bar"
async.function(function(response) {
  foo = "foobar";
  // module.exports = foo;  // having the export here breaks the app: foo is always undefined.
});

// having the export here results in working code, but without the variable being set.
module.exports = foo;
```

How can I export the module only once the async callback has been executed?

*edit* 
a quick note on my actual use-case: I'm writing a module to configure nconf (https://github.com/flatiron/nconf) in an fs.exists() callback (i.e. it will parse a config file and set up nconf).

Comment: Been playing around with my actual use-case, and nconf loads fine if nconf.file() is called with a non-existent file, so for now I don't need a solution. But am still interested in the approach.

Comment: I have the same question, I could like to export a promise, and the `require` load the dependency asynchronously. I think that is possible with babel formatter. However, I don't think a good solution for these. :(

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your export can't work because it is outside the function while the `foo`declaration is inside. But if you put the export inside, when you use your module you can't be sure the export was defined.

The best way to work with an ansync system is to use callback. You need to export a callback assignation method to get the callback, and call it on the async execution.

Example:

```
var foo, callback;
async.function(function(response) {
    foo = "foobar";

    if( typeof callback == 'function' ){
        callback(foo);
    }
});

module.exports = function(cb){
    if(typeof foo != 'undefined'){
        cb(foo); // If foo is already define, I don't wait.
    } else {
        callback = cb;
    }
}
```

*Here `async.function` is just a placeholder to symbolise an async call.*

In main

```
var fooMod = require('./foo.js');
fooMod(function(foo){
    //Here code using foo;
});
```

## Multiple callback way

If your module need to be called more than once you need to manage an array of callback:

```
var foo, callbackList = [];
async.function(function(response) {
    foo = "foobar";

    // You can use all other form of array walk.
    for(var i = 0; i < callbackList.length; i++){
        callbackList[i](foo)
    }
});

module.exports = function(cb){
    if(typeof foo != 'undefined'){
        cb(foo); // If foo is already define, I don't wait.
    } else {
        callback.push(cb);
    }
}
```

*Here `async.function` is just a placeholder to symbolise an async call.*

In main

```
var fooMod = require('./foo.js');
fooMod(function(foo){
    //Here code using foo;
});
```

## Promise way

You can also use Promise to solve that. This method support multiple call by the design of the Promise:

```
var foo, callback;
module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    async.function(function(response) {
        foo = "foobar"

        resolve(foo);
    });
});
```

*Here `async.function` is just a placeholder to symbolise an async call.*

In main

```
var fooMod = require('./foo.js').then(function(foo){
    //Here code using foo;
});
```

See [Promise documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: This wouldn't work if two separate (main) files call this function without foo being ready, right? Only one of their callback would be fired, whichever was the latest to call it..

Comment: In this case, yes. Beaucause we don't manage a callback stack. But it is easy to solve that with an array to store all the callback.

Comment: Details:ReferenceError: async is not defined

Comment: I am using Asnyc function to parse XML in webpack config. The module.exports and only be the config object, no function. What shall I do?

Comment: @1nstinct : Sorry! Here async.function is a placeholder name to represent an asynchronous process. There is a vendor module name async to create asynchonous call. But you need to install it in your project with NPM and load it with require. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu : I don't understand very well your question... In your module you read and parse an XML and you need to have finish your parsing to return the result directly in module.exports. In your main file, when your call require('myConfigModule') you need to have the parsed config in return of require, is'nt it ? So your need is synchronous (this is not a JS insult, in app lifecycle this is logic to have a synchronous config phase). Use synchronous methods of the fs API instead of classic async methods.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu I just had similar need with webpack 1 config. Promise approach worked for me (and the cb didn't) - maybe module export callbacks support for this case is on webpack side. I used Node 7.5.

Comment: @ArtemVasiliev : As it say in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/), the Promise is supported to configure Webpack asynchronously.

Comment: I have 2 questions: (1) What is the essence of the else block in your first example where you say `if(typeof foo != 'undefined'){
        cb(foo); // If foo is already define, I don't wait.
    } else {
        callback = cb;
    }`. (2) Does that block imply that `require`s to this module keep invoking it until it yields a value (from its async journey)? Or does it assume that only 1 callback will be given to the module throughout its lifetime i.e. subsequent calls can omit the `cb` argument?

Comment: @IWantAnswers, in this exemple the module can be require multiple time by diferent module that need use the `foo` value. But you don't know when it's happened. So when it's early and the `foo` value don't exist yet you store the callbacks to wait the return of the async call. At the end of the async process, all the stored callbacks are unstack and the array was no more used. At this point, if another module require this module and subscribe to get the `foo` value, the value is already set, so you bypass the store to directly execute the callback.

Comment: Keep in mind modules are singleton in node. The async process will execute only one time at the first require.

Comment: After reading this, I still do not understand how I can put an async function in a dot js, and call it from another dot js.  It is really confusing, and makes me want to abandon Node entirely.  I'm exhausted trying to figure so many things out - it's really a convoluted language, and I have doubts over my decision here to use Node for a server side language, when there are many other options not so confusing.  I don't understand any of the examples given.  Very confusing and alien syntax on every single line, with no explanation along the way.

Answer (score 28):

An ES7 approach would be an *immediatly invoked async function* in module.exports :

```
module.exports = (async function(){
 //some async initiallizers
 //e.g. await the db module that has the same structure like this
  var db = await require("./db");
  var foo = "bar";

  //resolve the export promise
  return {
    foo
  };
})()
```

This can be required with await later:

```
(async function(){

  var foo = await require("./theuppercode");
  console.log(foo);
})();
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference/implications between invoking it and not?

Comment: If you don't invoke the function, you export the function without executing it.

Answer (score 15):

ES6 answer using promises:

```
const asyncFunc = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Where someAsyncFunction takes a callback, i.e. api call
        someAsyncFunction(data => {
            resolve(data)
        })
    })
}

export default asyncFunc

...
import asyncFunc from './asyncFunc'
asyncFunc().then(data => { console.log(data) })
```

Or you could return the Promise itself directly:

```
const p = new Promise(...)
export default p
...
import p from './asyncModule'
p.then(...)
```

Comment: This is the correct, modern answer for ES6 and Promises. Thank you for this.

Comment: Question: Is there a reason why you are returning a function instead of the `Promise` directly? If you returned the `Promise` directly you could access it with `asyncFunc.then(...)`, right? Pretty new so want to get your opinion.

Comment: That would work too. I think when I wrote this example I was exporting a class with an async method so formulated it like a function. But you could just export the Promise like so: `const p = new Promise(...); export default p;` and then in your import module `import p from '...'; p.then(...);`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clarifying that. I suppose it's a personal preference or is there a best practices way to use one or the other?

Comment: I guess it depends on if you need to pass an argument to your async module, which is usually the case for me (eg. an `id` or other params). In the first example if `const asyncFunc = (id) => ...` then you could use `id` in your function. You'd call it like `asyncFunc(id).then(...)`. But if you don't need to pass any arguments, returning the Promise directly is fine as well.

Comment: Okay, great. Makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @inostia after `import`ing, do you know if the resolved promise response can be declared/executed/set once in the file and then used through a class and it's methods? The point of this would be so that each method in the class doesn't need to `p.then(...)` and could just use the resolved response.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach would be wrapping the variable inside an object.

```
var Wrapper = function(){
  this.foo = "bar";
  this.init();
};
Wrapper.prototype.init = function(){
  var wrapper = this;  
  async.function(function(response) {
    wrapper.foo = "foobar";
  });
}
module.exports = new Wrapper();
```

If the initializer has error, at least you still get the uninitialized value instead of hanging callback.

Comment: How do you get "foo" when you require the module?

Comment: var wrapper = require('wrapper');
console.log(wrapper.foo)

Answer (score 10):

You can also make use of Promises:

**some-async-module.js**

```
module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, 'someValueToBeReturned'), 2000);
});
```

**main.js**

```
var asyncModule = require('./some-async-module');

asyncModule.then(promisedResult => console.log(promisedResult)); 
// outputs 'someValueToBeReturned' after 2 seconds
```

---

The same can happen in a different module and will also resolve as expected:

**in-some-other-module.js**

```
var asyncModule = require('./some-async-module');

asyncModule.then(promisedResult => console.log(promisedResult)); 
// also outputs 'someValueToBeReturned' after 2 seconds
```

---

Note that the promise object is created once then it's cached by node. Each `require('./some-async-module')` will return the same object instance (promise instance in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Other answers seemed to be partial answers and didn't work for me. This seems to be somewhat complete:

**some-module.js**

```
var Wrapper = function(){
  this.callbacks = [];
  this.foo = null;
  this.init();
};
Wrapper.prototype.init = function(){
  var wrapper = this;  
  async.function(function(response) {
    wrapper.foo = "foobar";
    this.callbacks.forEach(function(callback){
       callback(null, wrapper.foo);
    });
  });
}
Wrapper.prototype.get = function(cb) {
    if(typeof cb !== 'function') {
        return this.connection; // this could be null so probably just throw
    }
    if(this.foo) {
        return cb(null, this.foo);
    }
    this.callbacks.push(cb);
}
module.exports = new Wrapper();
```

**main.js**

```
var wrapper = require('./some-module');

wrapper.get(function(foo){
    // foo will always be defined
});
```

**main2.js**

```
var wrapper = require('./some-module');

wrapper.get(function(foo){
    // foo will always be defined in another script
});
```

Comment: Why do you have `callback(null, wrapper.foo);` instead of `callback(wrapper.foo);`?

Comment: @IWantAnswers The first argument is error and second one is the result