# Returning a value from mongoose using NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The following code is written in NodeJS. I have a controller file as below,

```
var Controller = function(){

  var lib = require('../libraries/common').Common;

  this.name = "somename";
  this.id = lib.getId(this.name);

}
```

And in the common.js file the code is as follows,

```
var Common = function(){

  var Tool = require('../models/tools').Tools;

  this.getId = function(name){
    Tool.findOne({name: name},function(err, tool){
      console.log("tool = "+tool);  
    });
  }

}
module.exports.Common = new Common();
```

How do I achieve this? I want the value returned from the common.js to my controller. Is there any other way other than using async or callbacks? Please let me know if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports

Comment: @jperelli - Not exactly. Is it possible to achieve this without async? If not, how can I achieve with async? Sorry if its a stupid question, i am new to NodeJS.

Comment: thanks for your help. now i see that its not at all possible.