# Asynchronous function result in module initialization

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Assume this simple module:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose-util');

mongoose.myOwnCreateConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if(err) {
     console.log('log error somehow and make it die');
     module.exports = null;
  } else { 
     module.exports = connection;
  }
});
```

It won't work obviously, but how to manage that calls in context module initialization? What is the best practice here? Do I need to use function declaration only in module init? Thanks in advance. I am asking because express has app module where everything is initialized.

Comment: mongoose `createConnection` doesn't take a function as its argument: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-createConnection

Comment: it's not clear what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: Sorry, that was a simplifying, I will edit this ridiculously insane example :)

Comment: What I want to achieve is to export connection object in module. That is example, code is more complex but it does not matter here, it is not working even for this.

Comment: so why `var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database'); module.exports = db;` is not good?

Comment: module require is synchronous, I think using callbacks is the common practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports

Answer (score 1):

Require is synchronous operation. So this will not work, you can use this:

[Asynchronous nodejs module exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports)

Comment: That is quite clean solution, but using this I will just 'delay' (or rather postpone) async to another module - because I am using this 'async' module in other 'sync' modules, so it will require to make another async modules etc. I hope you get my point, but this solution is really nice.