# Electron app: Reference mainWindow object in another module?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am building an electron app, where the `mainWindow` object is created following the quick start: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/.

As per this quick start, it is created asynchronously. The problem that I run into, is that for instance when I want to send messages from main to renderer process, I need to reference the `mainWindow` object. If this happens to be in a module that I require, then I need a means to make this module know of the `mainWindow` object.

I could of course prepend it with `global.`, but I know that this is very much advised against. So I wish to do it more elegantly.

I came across this post: [Asynchronous nodejs module exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports); which appears to offer a solution. Taking the `main.js` file from the quick start (see above link, it's explicitly shown there), it appears I would add to the `createWindow` function

```
if( typeof callback === 'function' ){
  callback(mainWindow);
}
```

and export the `main.js` module as

```
module.exports = function(cb){
  if(typeof mainWindow !== 'undefined'){
    cb(mainWindow); 
  } else {
    callback = cb;
  }
}
```

Then, in a higher-level script, I would require as follows:

```
let main = require('./main.js');
let lib = require('./lib.js');  // Library where I need a mainWindow reference
main(function(window) {
    lib.doSomething(window);
});
```

where `lib.js` looks like

```
module.exports.doSomething = function(window) {
  // Do something with window object, like sending ipc messages to it
  window.webContents.send('hello-from-main', "hi!");
}
```

Although the simple case in the original post 'Asynchronous nodejs module exports' works fine, I cannot get it to work like described above; running the app it complains `Uncaught Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'webContents' of null`. This is also the case if I *directly* require `lib.js` within `main()`'s callback (which I know is also advised against).

I confess that I do not fully understand the simple case of the post, as I am rather new to node. This prevents me from fixing my own implementation of it, which I agree is blunt copy/pasting which reasonably should be expected to fail. Could somebody help me with how to correct above method, or advise me of a different approach to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have created the npm package [electron-main-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-main-window) for the same.

Install:

```
$ npm install electron-main-window

or 

$ yarn add electron-main-window
```

Usage:

```
// Import ES6 way
import { getMainWindow } from 'electron-main-window';
const mainWindow = getMainWindow();

// Import ES5 way
const mainWindow = require('electron-main-window').getMainWindow();

// e.g:
if(mainWindow !== null ){
  mainWindow.webContents.send('mainWindowCommunication', "This is a test message");
}
```

Comment: ES6 and ES2015 are the same thing. You meant ES5.

Comment: I ran into this issue & Googling brought me here. Tried your package & it works great. Thanks, Ganesh!

Comment: Googling for a couple of hours and couldn't find the answer. You just saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whooops! The devil is in the details... I had defined on top of `main.js`

```
let mainWindow = null, callback;
```

which caused the error! Should be

```
let mainWindow, callback;
```

then it works perfectly!

P.s. Instead of deleting my post, I opted for keeping it and answering myself for future reference of other people who need asynchronous exporting.