# Module exports async function undefined can't await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

So, as far as I google it, I understood that this problem relevant to async / promise coding. I waste over 2Hr plus with this, but still receive no result. Probably because I'm bad in it. So my identifier.js code is right and works fine, it returns the exact data I want. app.js is still good too. So where is the problem? I can't export result value from identifier.js, because if I do it, I receive 'undefined':

```
    const identifier = require("./db/ops/identifier");
    trade_log.create({
    Flag: req.body.Flag,
    Instrument: req.body.Instrument,
    Venue: req.body.Venue,
    Price: req.body.Price,
    Currency: req.body.Currency,
    Quantity: req.body.Quantity,
    Counterparty: req.body.Counterparty,
    Identifier: identifier(req.body.Counterparty),
    Commentary: req.body.Commentary,
```

but if I export it correcty (according to other guides), just like

```
let x = identifier(req.body.Counterparty).then(return value);
```

I receive an error at writing trade_log.create phase.

What is identifier.js? This module is a function that should request data from input form (req.body) via get and receive responce, return data & then in app.js it should be written in to MongoDB (writing works fine, already tested it)

app.js

```
const trade_log = require("./db/models/trade_log");
const identifier = require("./db/ops/identifier");
app.all('/log', function (req, res, next) {
let x = identifier(req.body.Counterparty.then();
trade_log.create({
    Flag: req.body.Flag,
    Instrument: req.body.Instrument,
    Venue: req.body.Venue,
    Price: req.body.Price,
    Currency: req.body.Currency,
    Quantity: req.body.Quantity,
    Counterparty: req.body.Counterparty,
    Identifier: x,
    Commentary: req.body.Commentary,
},function (err, res) {
    if (err) return console.log (req.body) + handleError(err);
    console.log(res);
});
next();
});
```

identifier.js:

```
const identifier = (name) => {
request(['options, name'], { 'whatever' })
.then(response => {
    /code that works fine
    let charset = result;
    return (charset);

module.exports = identifier;
```

I already tried in Identifier.js this export methods:

```
 function name(param) {
 //code here
 }
 module.exports = name();
```

and this:

```
 module.exports = {
    function: (name) => {
    //code here
 }
```

I also find relevant this SW answer: [Asynchronous nodejs module exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports/20239667) but I still can't understand what am I doing wrong.

How should I correct my code accrding to new ES6 standard or should I use another module.exports method?

Comment: `.then(return value)` is invalid js syntax

Comment: y, WebStrom mark this, but the funny thing is, according to console.log `identifier(req.body.Counterparty).then()` returns value correctly.
As I understand it, it's something about promises, that's why it returnes 'undefined' value, if I use it without .then

Comment: `.then(response => { let charset = result;
    return (charset);` what is this `result` you've plucked out of nowhere? why are you ignoring `response`? If `result` were something that is declared somehere that you haven't shown, why would you simply not `return result` rather than assigning it to some intermediate variable? How can that code work fine with a missing `});`?

Comment: maybe I miss '});' becaise I forget to copy a part of code, but trust me, it works fine. Actual problem is here in exporting function in app.js

for example, the only thing I want is to place `req.body` in MongoDB, but I can't do it, because I got a Identifier part, which is somekind of hash function (evaluted by Identifier.js module) from req.body.Counterpart. But I can't evaluate it, because I receive 'undefined' or 'indentifier in not a function' if I simply `module.export` it