# Exporting a dynamic import

Tags: javascript

I'd like to export a different package from a custom module based on an expression

```
const settings = {}

const init = (sentry) => {
  sentry.init(settings)
  return sentry
}

const pkg = async () => {
  let mod

  if (__CLIENT__) {
    mod =  await import('@sentry/browser').then(init)
  } else {
    mod = await import('@sentry/node').then(init)
  }
  return mod
}

const Sentry = pkg()

console.log({ Sentry })

export default Sentry
```

However, when i import this file later i receive a pending promise

```
import Sentry from 'config/sentry'
console.log(Sentry) // -> promise pending
```

Is it possible to default export the dynamically imported module at the top level?

## update

I ended up going with require instead of dynamic imports, as supported by webpack globals setup on my system

```
const Sentry = __CLIENT__ ? require('@sentry/browser') : require('@sentry/node')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports maybe something in here can help here?

Comment: Are you not getting error `await` can be only used inside async function ?

Comment: yes im sorry, let me update the code so that it is wrapped async

Comment: No, it's not possible - without [top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async functions *always* return a promise. That's by definition. Since dynamic imports also return promises (and are async), you can't export them, since exports have to be at the top level of a script. The best you can do is export the promise and include a `.then` handler in whichever script imports it; since you're returning `mod` from your async function, that will be passed to the `.then` handler's parameter for you to use there.