# Fetch, promises and modules: architecture problem

Tags: javascript

I am just venturing into multi-module JS applications so please bear with me here... I'm trying to find the best solution to what looks to be a simple architecture problem.

My application has a class called Alphabet. All instances of that class are built when the app is run, using data read from JSON files. The instances are then stored in a static array inside another class, say `Foo`, like this:

```js
// app.js (a part of it)

import Alphabet from './alphabet.js';
import Foo from './foo.js';

function getData(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    });
}

async function main() {
    const alphabets = [];
    const json = await getData('alphabets.json');
    for (const lang in json) {
        const dict = await getData(`dict/dict-${lang}.json`);
        const alphabet = new Alphabet(
            lang,
            json[lang].name,
            dict,
            json[lang].alphabet,
            json[lang].rtl
            );
        alphabets.push(alphabet);
    }
    Foo.init(alphabets);
    
    // Proceed with app setup
}

window.addEventListener('load', main);
```

The `Alphabet` class has a couple of static and instance methods which are used to make some calculations with the data.

```js
// alphabet.js

export default class Alphabet {

    static calculateFrequency(letters, dict) {
        let freq = []
        letters.forEach(letter => freq.push(Object.keys(dict).filter(word => word.startsWith(letter)).length));
        return freq;        
    }

    constructor(lang, name, dict, alphabet, rtl=false) {
        this.lang = lang;
        this.dict = dict;
        this.letters = alphabet.split('');
        this.name = name;
        this.rtl = rtl;
        this.frequency = Alphabet.calculateFrequency(this.letters, this.dict);
        this.maxFrequency = Math.max(...this.frequency);
    }
}
```

This worked fine until I reorganised the app to use modules and decided to move the whole Alphabet-building part into the `alphabet.js` module, so that it only exposes the `Alphabet` class when it's built. As long as Alphabet was exposed, I could store the class instances in a static array inside Alphabet instead of inside Foo, it even made more sense.

As it turns out, this has pushed my (very basic) understanding of promises and modules to its limits.

If I put the JSON-fetching code inside of `alphabet.js`, it needs to be triggered from `app.js`, perhaps with a static method such as `Alphabet.init()`. However, there is no way I can define a "`static async function`".

I tried exporting the loading function instead of the `Alphabet` class, like this:

```js
export default async function getAlphabets() {
    const alphabet = {};
    const json = await getData('alphabets.json');
    for (const lang in json) {
        const dict = await getData(`dict/dict-${lang}.json`);
        const item = new Alphabet(
            lang,
            json[lang].name,
            dict,
            json[lang].alphabet,
            json[lang].rtl
            );
        alphabet[lang] = item;
    }
    Alphabet.aStaticArray = alphabet;
    return alphabet;
}
```

...and triggering it from `app.js` like this:

```js
import getAlphabets from './alphabet.js';

function main() {
    getAlphabets().then(
      // Proceeed with the rest of app setup
    );
}
```

However since now I'm not exporting the `Alphabet` class from the module, I can't use the static array anywhere else.

I assume I could hack my way out of this by exporting both the function and the class, but it seems wrong. I'm trying to get a module to load whatever it needs to load and only expose one default class when it's finished. Any ideas on the most elegant way to set this up?

Thank you.

Comment: No way you can define a static async function? `class Foo { static async bar() {} }`. (But it’s not good to wrap functions in a class for no reason, and it won’t help with async problems.)

Comment: But in general, a module can’t initialize itself asynchronously and be imported and used synchronously. Your modules should provide (async) functions to *get* data and instances, and whatever wants to use those things should be responsible for holding onto them. (In other words, avoiding global state is both generally a good idea and a solution to this problem.)

Comment: Maybe some of these answers can help (the question is about nodejs but it shouldn't matter): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports

Comment: You'll probably want to `export class Alphabet { … }` and `export async function getAlphabets() { … }` alongside each other, not use a default export.