# How to fetch raw text from a url into node?

Tags: node.js, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from 2022 Advent Of Code into Vscode without copying and pasting the hundreds of lines of raw data into my IDE.

```js
// async function
async function fetchData() {
  let response = await fetch('https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1/input', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      cookie:
        'session=xxx',
    },
  })
  let data = await response.text()
  return data
}

const data = await fetchData()

export default data
```

This code runs perfectly in the browser dev tools, but when I try to run it in node, I get an error of `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: Add this code in async function

Comment: Do you want to use ES modules with top level await or CommonJS?

Comment: @morganney, I'm thinking of going with ES modules with top level await

Comment: Then be sure to use a node.js version >= 14 and configure your project to use ES modules, i.e., specify `"type": "module"` in the project's `package.json` file. Then you can create two modules if you like, one that consumes the data and one that produces the data, where the producing module has an export like `export default await fetchData()`, and the consuming module has an import like `import data from './path/to/producing/module.js`. This will cause the consuming module, at runtime, to only execute when the producing module finishes fetching the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous nodejs module exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports)